# Failed to load API definition. Fetch error INTERNAL SERVER ERROR /docs.json

Tags: python

I want learn API using swagger. I was input code like this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.json_encoder = LazyJSONEncoder

swagger_template = dict(
info = {    
    'title': 'API Documentation for Data Processing and Modeling',
    'version': '1.0.0',    
    'description': 'Dokumentasi API untuk Data Processing dan Modeling',
    }  #  host = LazyString(lambda: request.host)
)
swagger_config = {
    "headers": [],    "specs": [
        {            "endpoint": 'docs',
            "route": '/docs.json',        }
    ],    "static_url_path": "/flasgger_static",
    "swagger_ui": True,    
    "specs_route": "/docs/"
}

swagger = Swagger(app, template  = swagger_template, config= swagger_config)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
# jika terdapat folder docs# @swag_from('..\DS_1\docs\colors.yml')
#jika file yml satu level dengan file py
@swag_from('docs\hello_world.yml')
def hello_world():    
    json_response = {
       'status_code': 200,        
       'description': "Menyapa Hello World",
        'data ': "Hello World",    }
    response_data = jsonify(json_response)    
    return response_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run
```

and I run the code. But the code was error, and the error like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Peb.png)

anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you check the application logs?

Comment: in the log, the notification like that
* Serving Flask app '__main__' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit